# Mass rename / mass add controls with naming structure in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Environment: VS 2012 Winforms

Is there any process to mass add or mass edit elements with a specific naming structure?

For example, I add a combo box, setup all the common properties, font, size etc with id of 'userInput_01', copy and paste it, and the pasted control ID should be 'userInput_02' and if I do it 28 more times, I should have userInput_01-userInput_28

One step further, copy a group of controls, a group box (gb_userinput_01), combobox (cb_userInput_01), button (btn_search_01), label (lbl_search_01) and have them all increment to _02, _03 etc when pasted.

I always manage this by hand, and with ~20 group boxes of various controls in my current project would have liked to have saved a chunk of manual control naming with some such ability.  VS already auto increments a default name of controltype#, so the capability is there. From google, I saw a few results mentioning editing the designer files in a text editor, but that seems a crude hack to a solution that should exist in the designer.

Comment: No, using non-descript auto-generated names is supposed to hurt as much as possible.  *Twenty* groupboxes?  Oy vey.

Comment: So you're telling me that building out a data display of customers connected to a fiber telco switch with 16 blades of 32 ports each and each port serving 24 customers is purposely made hard because gb_cust01-gb_cust24 is non-descript?

Comment: Yes.  Cut the mouse umbilical cord and write code.  A simple for-loop.